# Differentiate $y=x + \frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{x+...}}}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If $y=x + \dfrac{1}{x+\dfrac{1}{x+\dfrac{1}{x+...}}}$ then $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ equal to ?

Comment: Then $y = x+\frac 1y\to y^2=yx+1\to 2y\text dy=x\text dy+y\text dx$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$y=x + \frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{x+...}}}$$
or $$y=x + \frac{1}{y}$$
or $$y^2-xy-1=0$$

So the roots of the above quadratic equation are as follows:
$$y=\frac{x\pm \sqrt{x^2+4}}{2}$$

So, $$\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=\frac{1\pm \frac{2x}{2\sqrt{x^2+4}}}{2}$$
or $$\color{red}{\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=\frac{x\pm \sqrt{x^2+4}}{2\sqrt{x^2+4}}}$$

Answer (score 2):

HINT:

$$y=x+\dfrac1y\iff y^2-xy-1=0$$

Either solve for $y$

Or use implicit Differentiation

Answer (score 0):

$$y=x + \frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{x+\frac{1}{x+...}}}=\frac{x\pm \sqrt{x^2+4}}{2}$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{1}{2} \left(1\pm\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+4}}\right)$$

Comment: The second equality in the first line is so so obvious, you should erase it. lol

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, if $y$ is well defined -- that is, if the limit exists -- then $y$ satisfies the quadratic equation $y^2-xy-1=0$.  This implies

$$y={x+\sqrt{4+x^2}\over2}\qquad\text{or}\qquad y={x-\sqrt{4+x^2}\over2}$$

The only thing I have to add here is that the limit (if it exists) is clearly positive if $x$ is positive and negative if $x$ is negative.  (The function is clearly not defined at $x=0$.)  Thus the function is properly

$$y=
\begin{cases}
{x+\sqrt{4+x^2}\over2}\quad\text{if }x\gt0\\\\
{x-\sqrt{4+x^2}\over2}\quad\text{if }x\lt0\\
\end{cases}$$

The derivative is straightforward to calculate.